# Reconstructing GitLab CI URL path to artifacts

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to construct a CI variable with an URL that points to the web access to GitLab CI artifacts; in order to use that variable for environments (MR previews). In short, for a project in group `topgroup`, subgroups `gr1/gr2`, project name `myproject` and gitlab pages deployed at domain `pages.example.org`, I want my variable to contain an URL like:

```
http://topgroup.pages.example.org/-/gr1/gr2/myproject/-/jobs/123456/artifacts/...[artifact path]...
```

The problematic part is the one between the two `/-/` parts, the rest is either static or can be constructed using `CI_JOB_ID` and `CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE`. The middle part doesn't seem to be possible to reconstruct from the currently available CI variables (at least not without taking them to the shell and sedding some parts in and out). The closest I got is:

- `CI_PAGES_URL` is ALMOST there, it gives the whole `http://topgroup.pages.example.org/gr1/gr2/myproject`, unfortunately *without* the `/-/` required for artifacts
- Constructing: `$CI_SERVER_PROTOCOL://$CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE.$CI_PAGES_DOMAIN/-/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/...` is almost there but unfortunately includes the `topgroup` in the `CI_PROJECT_PATH`, giving `http://topgroup.pages.example.org/-/topgroup/gr1/gr2/myproject/-/jobs/123456/artifacts/...`

Is there any way to construct this URL cleanly using simple means, without building it in the shell and re-exporting to gitlab variables?